# How to speed up a function in R

Tags: r, performance

I have the following instructions in R, which I'm using to change the values of variable `data$theme` according to the text inside `data$paragraph`, which contains long character strings:

```
  lines <- grep('banana|apple', file$paragraph)  # lines that match search terms
  for (i in 1:length(lines)){
    data[lines[i], 'theme'] <- 'Fruit'
  }
```

The problem with this command is that it's extremely inefficient with large datasets. My real case has over 200 thousand lines; it takes my computer over one second to do each substitution and I'll have to do over 40 thousand subs (and I can't afford to have this small step of my overall script take over 5 hours to complete). I'm desperately looking for a way to speed this up, I bet there's a simple solution but I can't think of a better way to get there. Help!

Comment: Have you tried `data[lines,'theme'] <- 'Fruit'`? To get more helpful answers, maybe provide a sample of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data[lines, 'theme'] <- 'Fruit'
```

R is able to work on entire vectors at once. Taking advantage of this is an easy way to speed things up.

Comment: Cool, this looks much better, but since it's not a lightning-fast procedure, I'd still like to have a counter. Inside the for I could just add `print(i, 'of', length(lines))`, but how can I do with with your one-liner there?

Comment: No, but with only 200k records, I'd be surprised if this takes very long. The call to `grep` should actually be the most time-consuming part.

Comment: You're right, you've just turned my 5-hour command into something that takes less than a couple of seconds. I actually feel kinda embarassed, since I've done `data[c(1, 2, 3), ]` in other situations and yet have been struggling with this for days. Thanks, Peyton, you've saved my weekend!

Comment: R is weird like that. :-) If you haven't already, you might want to take a look at The R Inferno, which goes over quirks like this: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf